# Unable to display current Location information in WP7 device

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing application in Silverlight for WP7 device, where used Bing Map to display Location information to user. I wants to display Current Location information when application loaded. But I am not able to retrieve current location information. Even I downloaded GPS related application from Market Place, that also not display current location information. So How to retrieve Current Location of device in WP7?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN has samples for retireving location and displaying it on a map: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744(v=vs.92).aspx

If you are not able to retrieve the location from any application verify that the device wide location setting has not been turned off as this woudl stop all apps ebign abel to retrieve location information.
You should also check the response you receive from the GeoCoordinateWatcher for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add below namespace

```
System.Device.Location
```

Then add

```
GeoCoordinate geoCoordiante=new GeoCoordinate();
```

Add **positionchanged event** handler

from there from **EventArgs** you can find

```
e.Position.Latitude
e.Position.Longitude
```

it gives the latitude n longitude of current place

Hope it helps you